# Java replaceall regex

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I have a little problem with Java string.replaceAll function with regex.

The string is like:

```
String s = "${start}textcontent${end}something else${start}textcontent${end}"
```

Now I try to use replaceall.

```
s.replaceAll("\\$\\{start\\}.*content.*\\$\\{end\\}", "Bla");
```

The result I expect is

```
Blasomething elseBla
```

But result I get is just

```
Bla
```

Comment: Try `.*?` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `Pattern.quote` to escape the special characters

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern
s.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("${start}")+"[a-z]*"+Pattern.quote("${end}"),"Bla"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `.*` is [*greedy*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy), and matches like this:

```
${start}textcontent${end}something else${start}textcontent${end}
├───┬──┤├───────┬─────────────────────────────────┤├──┬──┤├──┬─┤
    │           │      ┌──────────────────────────────┘      │
    │        greedy    │     ┌───────────────────────────┴┘  │
    │           │      │     │         ┌─────────────────────┘
├───┴────────┤  │   ├──┴──┤  │   ├─────┴────┤
\\$\\{start\\}  .*  content  .*  \\$\\{end\\}
```

To fix that, make them [*reluctant*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#reluc) by using `.*?`:

```
${start}textcontent${end}something else${start}textcontent${end}
├───┬──┤├─┬┤├──┬──┤├──┬─┤              ├──────┤├──┤├─────┤├────┤
    │     │    │      └──────────────────┐
    │     │    │  └┴───────────┐         │
    │     │    └────────┐      │         │
    │     └──────┐      │      │         │
├───┴────────┤   │   ├──┴──┤   │   ├─────┴────┤
\\$\\{start\\}  .*?  content  .*?  \\$\\{end\\}
```

The match would then repeat for the second sequence of `${start}...content...${end}`.

<sup>*In both cases, the second `.*` is matching an empty string.*</sup>